# How can I write code to show itself

Tags: c++, quine

How can I write a code to show itself (print code to console) using standard C++ only without any external library?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quine_%28computing%29

Comment: Quines are mostly done as an excercise.  If somebody tells you how to do it, then it becomes pointless.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tada: [http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quine_(computing)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quine_%28computing%29)

On a slightly more pragmatic note, almost no one ever does this. It's pointless. If you want to distribute source code, just put it into a tarball or zip file like a sane person.

Comment: It's an interesting learning experience.

Comment: Made much less interesting by asking someone else to do it for you.

Comment: Basically, the trick is to write your code so that it holds a string.  Inside that string is the _exact same code_, except where the contents of the string would be (inside itself), you have some magic key character (or two) that is nowhere else in the code.  You then display the string to the console until that key character, display the entire string, then display the string _after_ the key character.

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main () {
  string line;
  ifstream sourceFile(__FILE__);
  if (sourceFile.is_open())
  {
    while ( sourceFile.good() )
    {
      getline (sourceFile,line);
      cout << line << endl;
    }
    sourceFile.close();
  }

  else cout << "Unable to open source file"; 

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Calling `good()`, `eof()`, &c as a loop condition almost always results in bugger programs. Hint: Why does your program print an extra blank line?

Comment: See [here](http://ideone.com/VvnpW) for an alternative implementation.

Comment: Typo: "bugger programs". I *meant* buggy programs. Not really the same. :)